# Change instance template from VM instance in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My requirement is to change Instance template in existing VM instance but VM instance not showing any option of Changing instance template during editing already created VM instance.

Can you please clear me , is it possible to change instance template in existing VM Instance in google. if yes then how i can achieve this. i am very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change template. The template dictates the settings used at creation time. If you create a new template then you need to create a new instance based on the new template or manually edit the existing instance.

Comment: That is correct, here is the [documentation for reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates#how_to_update_instance_templates). As stated, you cannot update a template, but you can create a template based on an existing template or an existing instance. You can also override an instance template's fields when creating an instance with a template.